Lie Derivative of covariant derivative
I am reading book Integral Formulas in Differential Geometry by Kentaro Yano and in the page 26, I see a formula that I can't prove. Can someone help me to how to prove this:
$$(L_V\nabla)(X,Y)=X(f)Y+Y(f)X-g(X,Y)df$$
Where $V$ is conformal vector field with $L_Vg=2fg$. I think that we need to use these formulas $L_V\Gamma^i_{jk}=\nabla_i\nabla_jV^k+R^i_{jkm}V^m$ and $L_Vg_{ij}=\nabla_iV_j+\nabla_jV_i=2fg_{ij}$. can someone help me to prove this. Thanks in advance.
Here is my try:
$$(L_V\nabla)(X,Y)=L_V\nabla(X,Y)-\nabla([V,X],Y)-\nabla(X,[V,Y])$$
$$(L_V\nabla)(X,Y)=\nabla_V\nabla_XY-\nabla_X\nabla_VY-\nabla_{[V,X]}Y-\nabla_X\nabla_VY+\nabla_V\nabla_YX$$
$$(L_V\nabla)(X,Y)=\nabla_V\nabla_YX-\nabla_{[V,X]}Y+R(V,X)Y$$
write previous equation in index form
$$L_V\Gamma^k_{ij}=\nabla_i\nabla_jV^m+R^i_{jkm}V^m$$
After that i don't have much idea how to go further. I am trying to find some relation using $L_Vg_{ij}=\nabla_iV_j+\nabla_jV_i=2fg_{ij}$
still i can not use conformal factor. Other formula for $L_V\Gamma^k_{ij}$ can be find using Christoffel symbol formula $\Gamma_{ij}^{k}=\frac{1}{2}g^{kl}(\partial_ig_{lj}+\partial_jg_{li}-\partial_lg_{ij})$ and $L_Vg^{km}=-2fg^{km}$.

Show us how far you can get with this.

Dear @Deane. I am tryig to use Christoffel symbol formula $\Gamma^{k}{ij}=\frac{1}{2}g^{kl}(\partial_i g{lj}+\partial_j g_{li}-\partial_l g_{ij})$ and try to apply the Lie derivative with respect to $V$ on both sides then use the formulae given above.  But till now I could'nt succeed..

Show your calculations, so we can guide you.

Dear @Deane I have updated my question.
